# JPA connection error with Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to configure an JPA web application to work with JBOSS AS 7.1 and Oracle. This is the persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="dbcon" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/OracleDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>code.TestCon</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
        </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

I added this code to the standalone-full.xml:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                            <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl5</connection-url>
                            <driver>oracle</driver>
                            <user-name>C##test</user-name>
                                <password>test</password>
                </datasource>
<driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
                                    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
```

I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

I added also the odjbc6.jar file in modules/com/oracle/ojdbc6/main folder together with the module.xml. 
I want to point out that a JPA application as a standard Java project works without errors. Please advice what could be the problem.

Comment: Well, can you connect to orcl5 on the machine through sqlplus?

Comment: yes, with sqlplus and with a standard JPA application (non-web). But I have this problem when I try to configure the JPA to work with JBOSS as web applivation

Comment: Problem not in JPA or JBOSS. It is problem with oracle connection find problem in oracle listener configuration